# Computer Dell precision on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS UEFI

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a big problem wich my Linux Ubuntu : when i go to turn it off, my computer remains frozen with Dell splash screen and I will force by pressing the interrupt button. I trying to upgrade my mothercard but I can not to execute the .exe file for a flashbios. Or it's just a bad installation?

My computer is a Dell precision 7530 on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS UEFI wich this partitioning :

- **/ = 8 Go**
- **swap = 4 Go**
- **/boot = 4 Go**
- **/boot/efi = 512 Mo**
- **Bios Boot = 512 Mo**
- **/var = 10 Go**
- **/usr = 15 Go**
- **/opt = 5 Go**
- **/home = rest**

Comment: First thing to learn about Linux: It doesn't run Windows executables (there are emulators but NOT for a firmware update, never!). If you need to update the firmware there are alternative methods and, granted, that's not obvious from Dell's download pages. Now, please [edit] the question and add at least the Ubuntu release/version you installed and how (UEFI mode as it should be or Legacy?).

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes I know Linux doesn't run Windows executables but I read from Dell's download pages, we can run an exectubales wich the bios via a bootable usb key. But it doesn't work. And they only offer one .exe file for upgrade the bios.

Comment: I've created basic bootable USBs and put the Dell firmware executables on them for years. Dell's firmware update exes contain all their own dependencies and so can be run from pretty much any bootable media. I suggest looking into this more and giving us more details in your question regarding how you've created the bootable USBs and how they are failing.

Comment: As above. RE; your partitions, it's a typical newbie mistake to over-partition. **Ubuntu needs root (/) and an ESP (EFI System Partition), there's no point in creating anything else for a laptop!** Ubuntu has been using swapfile instead of a swap partition for many years, **root should be at least 25-30GB - you have 8GB(!!!), this is likely the reason for it to crash on shutdown -** you don't need "bios boot" - this is used ONLY for Legacy/BIOS in GPT drives and it's a 1-2MB unformatted.

Comment: I suggest you reinstall Ubuntu and let the installer do it for you automatically. The UEFI update is very likely NOT needed and NOT the problem.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you I will do it this week. 25-30Go for root partition for Ubuntu !? This partition was made wich Philippe Pinchon. But I'll go try this.

Comment: @music2myear I create the bootable USBs wich Ventoy.

Comment: @Thornasco Philippe Pinchon writes about **advanced administration** of servers, RHEL certifications, etc. - https://www.eyrolles.com/Accueil/Auteur/philippe-pinchon-121776/ - exactly what you AREN'T doing and shouldn't be doing before acquiring a solid foundation on basic Linux. Again, 8GB is batrely enough for the base OS and DE, any update will use almost all of the remaining free space. 25-30GB is the recommended minimum TODAY, not the recommendation from 20 years ago not even 10 years ago. But congrats on using Ventoy, great tool.

Comment: If you let the installer do it automatically by selecting an whole drive you'll end up with just the ESP (~512MB) and everything else as the root file system. It's this simple and it should be this simple for what you want and need. Even a separated `/home` is no longer recommended. While it used to be (sort of) useful for reinstallations from scratch for lazy people who don't do their backups, nowadays the many changes between releases make it counterproductive due to the old settings being preserved and potentially conflicting with the changes introduced.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Attempting to run an .exe on linux does not require any more answers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Ok thank you for your informations.  I'll going to do it like this.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta My question wasn't on how to run an .exe on Linux. I just trying to do it because I am not successful by run wich the Bios. But yes we can close this now.